# Matching images links containing spaces

Tags: php, regex

```
$update = ' sometext http://www.site1.com/images/some image with spaces.jpg some other text  http://www.site2.com/some_image.jpg';

preg_match_all('#(?:<\>]+href=\")?(?:http://)?(http(s?)://([^\s]*)\.(jpg|gif|png))#',       $update, $group_imagelink);
echo $group_imagelink[1][0];
echo $group_imagelink[1][1];
```

My regular expression doesn't want to extract a link from text with spaces.
I need to replace spaces in the link with `20%` for use after `copy()`, but I still want keep my text with spaces. How can I do this?

Also, is my code safe from things like http://www.myserver.com/virus.exe#fakeParam=.jpg?

Comment: Spaces simply aren't valid in a URL... your users shouldn't be putting them in in the first place and expecting it to work, if indeed that's where you're getting the text from.

Comment: And by which criteria do you want to differentiate text from those (invalid) space-ridden URLs? You can dumb down the regex with `.*?` in place of `[^\s]`, but that will open up another problem for URLs that will run into the next with a `.jpg` suffix.

Comment: thanks a lot mario , its helped me (.*?) and for url its ok because after i change a path and name .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

I replaced

```
   [^\s]*
```

with

```
   .*?
```