# Matching images links containing no spaces

Tags: php, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matching images links containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924318/matching-images-links-containing-spaces)

my code is:

```
preg_match_all('#(?:<\>]+href=\")?(?:http://)?(http(s?)://([^\s]*)\.(jpg|gif|png))#',$imagelinks, $group_imagelink);
echo $group_imagelink[1][0];
 echo $group_imagelink[1][1];
```

and content is (line-wrapped, originally in a single line):

> `$imagelinks = "http://www.site.com/images/img.jpghttp://site.com/2011/06/img.jpghttp://site.org/en/thumb/e/ec/img.jpghttp://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/img.jpghttp://www.site.com/assets/resources/2006/09/Civilization-3-0001.jpghttp://www.site.com/fr/images/screenshots/img.jpghttp://site.com/wp-content/gallery/img.jpghttp://site.com/images/G/01/software/detail-page/img.jpg";`

Can some one help me to have a correct pregmatch all to extract first , second etc... links from text with images and with out spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern does what you're looking for:

```
#(.+?(jpg|gif|png))#
```

And it will give you:

*0 => 
  array (

    0 => 'http://www.site.com/images/img.jpg',

    1 => 'http://site.com/2011/06/img.jpg',

    2 => 'http://site.org/en/thumb/e/ec/img.jpg',

    3 => 'http://site.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/img.jpg',

    4 => 'http://www.site.com/assets/resources/2006/09/Civilization-3-0001.jpg',

    5 => 'http://www.site.com/fr/images/screenshots/img.jpg',

    6 => 'http://site.com/wp-content/gallery/img.jpg',

    7 => 'http://site.com/images/G/01/software/detail-page/img.jpg',*

You can also test your preg_match's on this site, it saves a ton of time: [Functions Online](http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html)